Find the largest then calculate its factorial
I was assigned to write a Python program that prompts the user to enter five numbers, one by one. The program should determine and display the largest number entered. After identifying the largest number, calculate and display its factorial if it is a positive integer.
def max_factorial():
    largest_n = int(input(''))
    result = 1

    for i in range (4):
        n = int(input(''))
        if n >= largest_n:
            largest_n = n
    
    print (largest_n)
    
    if largest_n >= 0:
        for i in range (1, largest_n+1):
            result *= i
        print(result)
    else:

        print('NoProceed')

max_factorial()

example input 1:
4
3
3
5
2

output:
5
120

example input 2:
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5

output:
-1
NoProceed

My teacher uses this website called 'theta dmstech' for our assignment, it uses python3. For some reason it doesn't accept my answer. I've tried using import math and using array to store the numbers then using max() to find the largest numbers, and nothing works. I've also tried for it to refuse decimal numbers to return 'NoProceed', still not accepted. I don't know if there's a problem with my code, the question, or how the website handle accepted answer.

You should ask your teacher what the expected result is in the second example. As far as I can tell from the information you have provided, your program does what it should (maybe it should simply not print NoProceed).

One other thing is that the assignment says "calculate and display its factorial if it is a positive integer" and your program does it also if the number is 0.

from math import factorial

def max_factorial():
    # Define a list
    nums = []
    # Fill it
    for _ in range(5):
        nums.append(int(input())) 

    max_num = max(nums)

    print(max_num) 
  
    if max_num > 0: # Keep your attention
        print(factorial(max_num))

max_factorial()

If you have told the condition of the task correcty, then note that 0 is not a positive number, it's non-negative and non-positive, there is a difference, maybe that was the problem

I have no idea about the OJ you are taking about the following code should work waht you are expecting so you can try following code
def max_factorial():
    numbers = [int(input()) for _ in range(5)]
    largest_n = max(numbers)
    print(largest_n)
    
    if largest_n > 0:
        result = 1
        for i in range(1, largest_n + 1):
            result *= i
        print(result)
    elif largest_n == 0:
        print(1)
    else:
        print("NoProceed")

max_factorial()

